# Criterion for external product of two cyclic groups to be cyclic.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be two cyclic groups. Then $G \oplus H$ is cyclic if order of $G$ and order of $H$ are relatively prime.

Proof. Suppose that $|G|=m$, $|H|=n$ and let $\gcd(m, n)= t$, $t \neq 1$.
Let $G=\langle g\rangle$ and $H=\langle h\rangle$. Then $\langle g^{\frac{m}{t}}, e\rangle$ and $\langle e,h^{\frac{n}{t}}\rangle$ are two distinct subgroups of order $t$ in $G \oplus H$.

How should I prove that these two subgroups are distinct ( i.e. they are not isomorphic)?

Comment: Hey P G, I fixed your post. Please have a look to see what I fixed it so that you can do it yourself next time. :)

Comment: These subgroups are distinct (their intersection is $\langle e, e\rangle$), but they are isomorphic: both are cyclic of order $t$.

Answer (score 0):

The subgroups are isomorphic. They are both cyclic of order $t$. They are still distinct subgroups though in the sense they are not the same subgroup of $G \oplus H $ since $ ( g^{ \tfrac{m}{t} } , e ) \notin \langle e , h^{ \tfrac{n}{l} } \rangle $.

As a side note I'm not sure if the proof is proving the original statement. You can reword the original proposition as "If $G$ and $H$ are relatively prime then $G \oplus H $ is cyclic."

But the proof seems to be trying to prove the statement "If $G$ and $H$ are NOT relatively prime then $G \oplus H $ is not cyclic" - which I don't think it equivalent to the above.

Comment: I was trying to prove it by contradiction

Comment: @PG: That's not how a proof by contradiction works. You don't negate the hypothesis. If you were trying to prove it by contradiction, you would need to assume that $G$ and $H$ have relatively prime orders **and** that $G\oplus H$ is not cyclic.